# Storing options for pgfkeys inside macro

Tags: expansion, pgfkeys

I want to define some options as a list of key-value pairs inside a macro and use that macro inside a command that takes pgfkeys-style options. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{
    /example/.is family, /example,
    .unknown/.code = {
        (\pgfkeyscurrentkeyRAW,#1)
        \typeout{DEBUG \pgfkeyscurrentkeyRAW}
    }
}

\newcommand{\defvalues}[2][]{
    \pgfkeys{/example, #1}
}

\begin{document}

\def\mylist{c=3,d=4}

\defvalues[a=1,b=2]{}

\expandafter\defvalues\expandafter[\mylist]{}

\expandafter\defvalues\expandafter[f=6,\mylist]{}

\end{document}
```

In the last line, `\mylist` is not expanded correctly.

Expected output in the document:

```
(a,1) (b,2) (c,3) (d,4) (f,6) (c,3) (d,4)
```

Actual output:

```
(a,1) (b,2) (c,3) (d,4) (f,6) (c=3,d=4)
```

Alternatively, when running `pdflatex test.tex|grep DEBUG`, expected output:

```
DEBUG a
DEBUG b
DEBUG c
DEBUG d
DEBUG f
DEBUG c
DEBUG d
```

Actual output:

```
DEBUG a
DEBUG b
DEBUG c
DEBUG d
DEBUG f
DEBUG c=3,d=4
```

How do I get `\mylist` to expand before it is passed to `pgfkeys`?

Comment: You should use the `.style` handler to define your list: `\pgfkeys{/example/mylist/.style={a=1,b=2}}`.

Comment: Does that mean I need to know the name of the macro (in this case `\mylist`) in advance? I'd like to provide everything you see in the preamble as a package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
\newcommand{\defvalues}[2][]{
    \edef\opts{/example, #1}
    \expandafter\pgfkeys\expandafter{\opts}
}
```

This works as expected. I guess it has to do with the fact that `\expandafter` doesn't work on `[]` the way it does on `{}`. Or rather, in the third case, it's only expanding `f`, not the entire contents of the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the `.style` handler to define two lists.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{
  /example/.is family,
  /example,
  .unknown/.code = {
    (\pgfkeyscurrentkeyRAW,#1)
    \typeout{DEBUG \pgfkeyscurrentkeyRAW}
  }
}

\newcommand{\defvalues}[2][]{\pgfkeys{/example,#1}}
\def\mylist{c=3,d=4}
\defvalues[mylist/.style/.expand once={\mylist}]{}
\defvalues[mylist2/.style={g=8,h=45}]{}

\begin{document}
\defvalues[a=1,b=2]{}

\defvalues[mylist]{}

\defvalues[f=6,mylist,mylist2]{}
\end{document}
```

Output:

```
(a,1) (b,2)
(c,3) (d,4)
(f,6) (c,3) (d,4) (g,8) (h,45)
```